# DataTemplate Doesn't Apply

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and some help would be appreciated.

I got a resource Dictionary where I am trying to style a `ListViewItem` or `ItemTemplate` ListView's Property, But both ways have failed.

****First way:****

Dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Height="45" Width="45" Fill="Gray"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Background="LightSkyBlue">
        <ListViewItem>Text cannot be seen</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

"This one doesn't show any text"

**Second Way:**

Dictionary

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="LeftMenuButtons">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Height="45" Width="45" Fill="Gray"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

MainWindow

```
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LeftMenuButtons}" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ListViewItem>No Effect for DataTemplate Only Text Appears</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

This Doesn't apply anything in DataTemplate.

If possible I would like to know what is going wrong in both two ways ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Way - Control Template

Please specify the `TargetType` of the control template explicity.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
```

You could also give the list view item style a name, so it is not applied on all items in your scope, but only to the target list view.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
```

Make sure, that you assign the style to your target list view.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          Background="LightSkyBlue"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
```

### Second Way - Data Template

First, data templates only work if your items are assigned via the `ItemsSource` property. If you directly assign `ListViewItem`s to your list view, they will not be affected. You have to bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection. Second, you do not use a `ContentPresenter` in the data template, you bind to properties of the objects in the `ItemsSource` collection. In this example you would have a collection of `string`s that are assigned to the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`. Maybe this is beyond the scope of your question.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding StringCollection}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LeftMenuButtons}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="LeftMenuButtons"
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Ellipse Height="45"
                 Width="45"
                 Fill="Gray"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was curious about the datatemplate part as it sometimes gives me Exception errors in the designer ... didn't know it doesn't accept contentpresenter.

Comment: Items aren't selectable anymore tho ... do you have the same issue?

Comment: @SaidAmir That is expected in the first case. `ControlTemplate` defines the appearance of the associated control. This also includes the states of the control when getting selected or focused. This is why content templates are complex and you should know what you are doing when you modify them. You should rely on the second approach if you can, because it does not change the list view item control template, just the contents of a `ListViewItem`. Or in other words, change the display of your **data**, not of the **control** that displays it.

Comment: @SaidAmir In short, since you overwrote the `ContentTemplate` of the `ListViewItem`, the styles for selection and highlighting are lost, too , and you would have to define them yourself.

Comment: so its more like recreating the control template not editing it ... makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. You just forgot to write ControlTemplate TargetType.

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle"  TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Height="45" Width="45" Fill="Gray"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it's kinda weird to mention TargetType twice since I already did that in the higher scope.

Comment: It is good idea in WPF xaml to write TargerType for all styles, templates and so on whatever you use them)

Comment: @SaidAmir These are two different types. The `Style` and the `ContentTemplate` each have a `TargetType` property and it does not get propagated down autmatically, this has nothing to do with inheritance.